# Working example of AngularJS and Bootstrap DatePicker directive?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I've seen a variety of github directive examples, but none include a working JSFiddle and I've not been able to get any of them to work. Surprised this isn't in [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) by this point.

Comment: perfectly good working one here  :  http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker

Comment: The problem with Angular-Strap is that it takes a very different approach to directives than the Bootstrap-UI project from the AngularJS team at Google. In fact the approach taken by Angular-Strap is prone to break when the Bootstrap.js file changes, where as that is not the case for Angular Bootstrap-UI.

Comment: charlietfl, perhaps the questions needs clarification, however my comment about it's architecture is valid and well documented in comparisons between Angular Bootstrap-UI and Angular-Strap.

Answer (score 14):

please see this directive, a working calendar [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nabeezy/HB7LU/209/):
http://jsfiddle.net/nabeezy/HB7LU/209/

```
myApp.directive('calendar', function () {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
                    $(el).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        onSelect: function (dateText) {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        })
```

Comment: not comming correct format in the above link

Comment: but it does not allow you to change to year format..or month format

Answer (score 6):

Lets say this is in your view.html:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
          var element = angular.element($('#datepicker'));
          var controller = element.controller();
          var scope = element.scope();

          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.doSomethingWithDate(ev.date);
          });
        });
        </script>
```

And then in your controller.js:

```
$scope.doSomethingWithDate = function (date){
  alert(date);
};
```

That's it, it works :)

Answer (score 4):

I hope this helps, I was looking for a simple example, but I couldn't find it, I found one but full of code and links and I cleaned it, here is the most simple working example of datepicker using angular bootstrap:

---> [sample page](http://lionfishtechnologies.com/developers/samples/angular_bootstrap_datepicker/datePicker.html) <---

Comment: Yes, it works all right. Just a pity you didn't make a Plunk or post your code. We can see _that_ it works, but not _how_ it works,  which is not really very helpful :-(

Comment: its working, can you please share the jsfiddle or plunker for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check now. You forgot to add `jquery` and  `css` in it.

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24804/)